# Volume of Solids Generalized

Tags: calculus, derivatives, solid-of-revolution

I want to make sure I'm understanding this correctly.
If a continuous, nonnegative function $f(x)$ on $[a,b]$ was revolved about some axis, where it grows by $x$ in $\Delta x$ intervals, then the rate of change of volume is the area of the base of the cylinder. So then volume is the area times its height, then $$dV=\pi((r_o)^2-(r_i)^2)dx$$

If instead, the cylinder's height grows by $y$ in $\Delta y$ intervals then $$dV=\pi((f^{-1}_o(y))^2-(f^{-1}_i(y))^2)dy$$
Where the radii is $x$ in terms of $y$.

---

Now if the radius grows by $x$ in $\Delta x$ intervals, then the rate of change of volume is no longer the area of the base, but the area of the lateral side of the cylinder. Then $$dV=2\pi x f(x) dx$$
If instead, the radius grows by $y$ in $\Delta y$ intervals, then $$dV = 2\pi f^{-1}(y)y dy$$

Am I describing this correctly?

Comment: You'd better specify carefully about which axis you are rotating in each of your three discussions.

Comment: I figured if something is growing by $\Delta y$ intervals then that implies the curve is being rotated about the $y$ axis. The saying "radius/height grows by ____ in ___ intervals" is the kind of language my professor uses, and its the kind of language used in exams so I'm trying to make sure I'm interpreting it correctly

Comment: The point is that you can compute volume by chopping either *perpendicular* to or *parallel* to the axis. This is what you should be thinking about. The first leads to cross-sectional areas, the second leads to cylindrical shells.

Comment: Rotating the graph of $f$ about the $x$ or $y$ axis will sweep out a surface, not a solid. In order to sweep out a solid you will have to have some region, presumably partially bounded by the graph of $f$. Which region do you have in mind?

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales I think the region would be the area under the curve of $f$ on some interval $[a,b]$. I mean, it could be even a part of this area, but generally its some area $R$ under the curve and above the x-axis.

Comment: @Lex_i That makes sense if revolving about the $x$-axis. But if revolving about the $y$-axis you will want to use cylindrical cross-sections, not annular cross-sections.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales that makes sense, thank you